# Remove space between "Theorem" and theorem number

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

I'm trying to create a dynamic numbering system for a survey, with questions that I can also reference.

I would like to see

**Q1.** *What is your age?*

but playing around with `\newtheorem` all I can get is

**Q 1.** *What is your age?*

I have not been able to figure how to alter `\newtheoremstyle` to remove the space between "Q" and the number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{question}{Q}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
What is your age?

\label{q:age}

\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\newtheorem{question}{Q\ignorespaces}
```

Answer (score 5):

With [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) you can update the way your theorem displays by creating a custom layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER  
]{nospacetheorem}
\declaretheorem[style=nospacetheorem,name=Q]{question}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
What is your age?
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Of course, there is no real need for a theorem here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{question}
\newenvironment{question}
  {\par\noindent
   \refstepcounter{question}%
   \textbf{Q\thequestion.}~\itshape\ignorespaces}
  {\par\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
What is your age?
\end{question}

\end{document}
```